# Importing text file into Matlab, dimension not maintained

Tags: matlab, matrix, import, dimension

I am trying to upload a text file into matlab as a matrix and then process based on user input so selected data are selected.

These are the first few rows of the data.

```
The United States of America, Deaths (1x1)     Last modified: 16-Nov-2012, MPv5 (May07)

Year     Age        Female             Male            Total
1933      0          52615.77         68438.11        121053.88
1933      1           8917.13         10329.16         19246.29
1933      2           4336.92          5140.05          9476.97
1933      3           3161.59          3759.88          6921.47
1933      4           2493.84          2932.59          5426.43
1933      5           2139.87          2537.53          4677.40
1933      6           1939.70          2337.76          4277.46
1933      7           1760.47          2163.90          3924.37
1933      8           1602.20          2015.97          3618.17
1933      9           1464.88          1893.96          3358.84
```

A larger part of the data is present here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4njypwmrxwxzl7/USA.Deaths_1x1.txt?dl=0

The problem I am facing is that everytime I use `T=readable()` to read in the data, the dimension of T is `m x 1` table, rather than a `m x 5` table.

I also tried to change the txt file into a csv file, but the data has non-numeric entries.

What could I do to accomplish this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: look at the doc for [`importdata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) then try: `datatable=importdata('USA.Deaths_1x1.txt',' ',3)`

Comment: @Hoki do you know why it only imported 111 rows, but not all the 10000+ rows

Comment: yeah the import format stumbled at the first hiccup. I made a more robust answer (it imports the whole file) but a few lines remain faulty (for the old people, poor them).

Comment: I think it only imports 111 row because the 111th data for age is 110+ which is not a numeric. I have a 110+ age for each year so that's about one in every 111 row

Comment: Can you show me what you came up with? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your format of data, most straight forward import functions (`importdata`, `dlmread`, etc ...) will fail.

[`textscan`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) has a few parameters which will allow you to import the full file without breaking at the first irregular line, however a few faulty lines will contain `NaN`.

```
%// Define special values which can be encoutered
specialValues = {'110+','other_special_values'} ;
formatSpec = '%n%n%f%f%f' ;

%// Read the file, treating special values 
fileID = fopen('USA.Deaths_1x1.txt');
C = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, ...
    'delimiter'     , ' ', ...
    'headerlines'   ,3, ...
    'treatAsEmpty'  , specialValues, ...
    'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1 );

fclose(fileID);

%// Convert cell array to matrix
data = cell2mat(C) ;
```

---

If you really need the faulty lines data, you'll have to write a more custom parser with the low level function `fscanf` and account for every edge case (unconventionnal line) that you may encounter.